# Не работает выход из цикла с запросами

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть цикл, из которого нужно выйти при изменение информации в базе, это не получается... я искал информацию на 3 форумах( по более масштабному вопросу) но именно это и есть ошибка того самого масштабного вопроса.... надо завершить цикл, после того как get перестанет быть равным информации в базе

```
$last_msg_id = $_GET['timestamp'];
do {
    $result = R::findLast('messages', 'dialog = ? ',array($_GET['getmess']));
    $last_msg_id = $result->date;
    sleep(1);
} while ($last_msg_id == $_GET['timestamp']);
echo $last_msg_id;
```

Comment: Посмотрите чему равен `$result->date`

Comment: $result->date = число

Comment: А timestamp и getmess вы передаёте на основании информации в базе? Или только идентификатор диалога?

Comment: ну это упрощённый пример long pollinga  сначала они оба равны, но после  в цикле надо бесконечно проверять базу про наличие новых данных

Comment: Как то не до конца описана проблема, как вы получаете данные от клиента?  вы каждую секунду запрос получаете да? я правильно понимаю? и еще опишите вообще зачем нужен этот цикл? Для решения какого вопроса оно вам нужно?

Comment: Он нужен для Long pollinga, я получаю от юзера дату последнего сообщения, если она равна дате последнего сообщения -> зацикливаем и проверяем базу, остановить цикл когда в бд будут новые данные

Comment: Эм...  А для чего это всё? Типа чат? Не проще тогда на сокетах? Или допустим каждые н секунд опрашивать сервер на непрочитанные сообщения?

Comment: И циклом ждать новые сообщение это ужас, если честно, у вас может быть бесконечная загрузка страницы которая насколько помню через какое то время выльется в пятисотку

Comment: Если конечно у вас не VPS

Comment: Вспомните старые веб чаты которые опрашивали сервер каждые Н секунд, при том на некоторых сайтах можно было выбирать частоту обновления. Правда могу предположить что если будет много клиентов то сервер они положут знатно

Comment: Нет, каждую секунду я опрашивал( не выгодно) долгие опросы... больше кпд